# Middle-Tapped Transformer Full-Wave Rectifier Vs. Full-Wave Bridge Rectifier

Tags: ac, transformer, rectifier, bridge

In terms of output voltage, which one of these would be best?  Coming into this, I would have to say the center-tapped transformer full-wave rectifier would allow the most accurate output voltage (only 1 diode voltage drop).

I've always heard: Cost of the middle-tapped transformer is greater than 2 more diodes.  Is this all that it comes down to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of the diodes is one thing.

The cost of adding a center tap is another.

Increased efficiency by losing a diode drop is another thing.

You can get 24% [more DC current](http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf) out of the same weight and size transformer with the 4-diode full wave bridge.

So if the filtered DC voltage is more than 2-3V, the full wave rectifier comes out ahead, assuming the diodes-vs-centertap is a wash.

Comment: Also the reverse peak voltage for the diodes is less (half) with the bridge although this seldom translates in real cost savings. From the free web resources on this topic, I recommend the Motorola (now On Semi) rectifier application handbook HB214/D (chapter 6 and 8) as having a much more detailed analysis/comparison than that Hammond pdf, by the way.